# How to enable/disable Firewall?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, firewall

The [INetFwPolicy2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365309(v=vs.85).aspx) interface allows an application or service to access the firewall policy.

I am using visual studio 2017.

Question is related to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33700472/2451446

Code is little different and I have problem to disable fire wall.

Logic before disable fire wall is ok.

```
        public Task<StatusCodeResult> ResetFirewallStatus()
        {
            Type netFwPolicy2Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");
            dynamic mgr = Activator.CreateInstance(netFwPolicy2Type);

            var fwCurrentProfileTypes = mgr.CurrentProfileTypes;

            // Get current status
            bool firewallEnabled = mgr.FirewallEnabled(fwCurrentProfileTypes); // return true

            // Disables Firewall
            mgr.FirewallEnabled(false); //breaks here !!!!


            return Task.FromResult<StatusCodeResult>(Ok());
        }
```

error message is:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected
>   range.'

I tried to use `set_FirewallEnabled(fwCurrentProfileTypes,false);`

and also `put_FirewallEnabled(fwCurrentProfileTypes,false)`

In this case error is:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:
>   ''System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for
>   'set_FirewallEnabled'' ('put_FirewallEnabled'')

---

Edit

MY SOLUTION:

```
const int domainProfile = 1;
const int privateProfile = 2;
const int publicProfile = 4;

public bool EnableDisableFirewall(bool enableFirewall)
{
    dynamic mgr = getFwPolicy2();

    mgr.FirewallEnabled[domainProfile] = enableFirewall;
    mgr.FirewallEnabled[privateProfile] = enableFirewall;
    mgr.FirewallEnabled[publicProfile] = enableFirewall;

    return enableFirewall;
}

public bool IsFirewallOn()
{
    dynamic mgr = getFwPolicy2();

    // Get current status
    var isDomainProfileEnabled = mgr.FirewallEnabled(domainProfile);
    var isPrivateProfileEnabled = mgr.FirewallEnabled(privateProfile);
    var isPublicProfileEnabled = mgr.FirewallEnabled(publicProfile);

    return isDomainProfileEnabled && isPrivateProfileEnabled && isPublicProfileEnabled;
}

private object getFwPolicy2()
{
    Type netFwPolicy2Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");
    dynamic mgr = Activator.CreateInstance(netFwPolicy2Type);
    return mgr;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems, writing this code late-bound does not exactly help to get this right.  Adding a reference to c:\windows\system32\firewallapi.dll so you can use the INetFwPolicy2 interface directly helps you get it right.  One quirk you are battling is that the FirewallEnabled property is an *indexed* property.  There is no equivalent in the C# language. Anyhoo, doing it late-bound requires:

> bool firewallEnabled = mgr.FirewallEnabled(fwCurrentProfileTypes);

The MSDN documentation specifically warns about this, you cannot use the value returned by CurrentProfileTypes.  It requires specifying a [*specific* profile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366303(v=vs.85).aspx).  I recommend you use:

```
  int profile = 2;   // 1=domain, 2=private, 4=public
  bool firewallEnabled = mgr.FirewallEnabled[profile];
```

Note the use of the [angle brackets], allowed for indexed properties in the specific case of COM-implemented properties.

> mgr.FirewallEnabled(false); //breaks here !!!!

You have to select the specific profile that you want to disable.  Proper syntax looks like:

```
  mgr.FirewallEnabled[profile] = false;
```

Beware that you can only tinker with the firewall when your programs runs elevated with admin privileges.  Add the [required manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818776/17034) if you haven't done so yet.